# Logical OR in XPath? Why isn't | working?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xsl-fo, dita

I've got an XSLT template which counts topics at all levels, for use in labeling those topics with numbering in DITA projects I've got.

```
<xsl:template match="*[contains(@class, ' bookmap/chapter ')] | *[contains(@class, ' map/topicref ')] [not(ancestor-or-self::*[contains(@class,' bookmap/frontmatter ')])]" mode="topicTitleNumber"> 
    <xsl:number format="1 " count="*[contains(@class, ' map/topicref ')] [not(ancestor-or-self::*[contains(@class,' bookmap/frontmatter ')])] | *[contains(@class, ' bookmap/chapter ')]" level="multiple"/> 
</xsl:template>
```

I'm trying to add an additional exclusion to what gets counted though, for when a `topicref` class has a `title` element with an `outputclass` of `noNum`.

```
<xsl:template match="*[contains(@class, ' bookmap/chapter ')] | *[contains(@class, ' map/topicref ')] [not(ancestor-or-self::*[contains(@class,' bookmap/frontmatter ')])]" mode="topicTitleNumber"> 
    <xsl:number format="1 " count="*[contains(@class, ' map/topicref ')] [not(ancestor-or-self::*[contains(@class,' bookmap/frontmatter ')] | *[contains(title/@outputclass, 'noNum')])] | *[contains(@class, ' bookmap/chapter ')]" level="multiple"/> 
</xsl:template>
```

Shown above, I added `| *[contains(title/@outputclass, 'noNum')]` after the first `not` statement, thinking that would function as an additional condition in which the `count` call would skip over when the template was called (i.e. *...not an ancestor-or-self with [criteria] or a topic with title outputclass attribute of 'noNum'...)*. However it appears that the criteria I added is treated as something the template **does** match on and count.

Assuming that I am correct on the last point, I believe I need to put that condition inside of its own 'not' statement, but I'm not sure how to do that with the conditions already present in the XPath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XPath `|` is a set **union operator**, not a logical OR.

### Union operator, `|`

[**XPath 1.0**](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#node-sets)

> The `|` operator computes the union of its operands, which must be node-sets.

[**XPath 2.0+**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#combining_seq)

> The `union` and `|` operators are equivalent. They take two node sequences as operands and return a sequence containing all the nodes that occur in either of the operands.

---

### Logical OR, `or`

Use `or` instead for [**logical OR**](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#NT-OrExpr) .

---

### Complex XPath still not working?

Break it down to smaller parts:

1. Does `//*[contains(@class, ' bookmap/chapter ')]` select what you expect?  Repeat for each of the most basic parts of your logical expression *individually*.
2. Combine those individually verified terms or predicates, one at a time, and observe that each step along the way, there are not surprises.
3. Repair any discrepancies between expected and actual results before combining additional terms.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Though `or` still doesn't work, so my XPath is still wrong somewhere apparently.

Comment: It's hard to say more without seeing your XML, but I've added some generic debugging tips for complex XPath expressions joined by logical connectors.