# How a write a common XPath for same text displayed for different HTML tags?

Tags: html, xml, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I want to write a common XPath for the result displayed for my searched text 'Automation Server'

The same text is displayed for `td` HTML tags as well as for `div` html tags as shown below, and I wrote XPath as below based on my understanding by going through different article

```
displayed_text = //td[contains(text(),'Automation Server') or div[contains(text(),' Automation Server ')]

<td role="cell" mat-cell="" class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-siteName mat-column-siteName ng-star-inserted">Automation Server</td>

<div class="change-list-value ng-star-inserted"> Automation Server </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operator you are looking for in XPath is `|`. It is a union operator and will return both sets of elements.

The XPath you are looking for is

```
//td[contains(text(),'Automation Server')] | //div[contains(text(),'Automation Server')]
```

Answer (score 3):

This XPath,

```
//*[self::td or self::div][text()[normalize-space()='Automation Server']]
```

will select all `td` or `div` elements with an immediate text node whose normalize string value equals `'Automation Server'`.

### Cautions regarding other answers here

- `|` is ***not*** logical-OR or "OR-like".

  It is a ***union*** operator over node sets (XPath 1.0) or sequences (XPath 2.0+), ***not*** boolean values.
  See: [Logical OR in XPath? Why isn't | working?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52900626/290085)
- `contains(text(), "string")` only tests the *first* text node child.
  See: [Why is contains(text(), "string" ) not working in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71253563/290085)

Answer (score 2):

A few alternatives to [JeffC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73438251/3710053) answer, using common properties for both:

**1. use the `*` as a wildcard for any element:**

```
//*[contains(@class,'ng-star-inserted') and normalize-space(text())='Automation Server']
```

**2. use in addition the `local-name()` function to narrow down the names of the elements:**

```
//*[local-name()[.='td' or .='div']][contains(@class,'ng-star-inserted') and normalize-space(text())='Automation Server']
```

The [normalize-space()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space) function can be used to clean-up the optional white space, so a [= operator](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_operators.asp) can be used.

Comment: I like this compressed format... `[local-name()[.='td' or .='div']]`. I've never seen that before.

Comment: @JeffC: Then you'll really like `[self::td or self::div]` for both conciseness and for not defeating namespaces (which may not matter here but do in other contexts).

Comment: Your solution too works for me and a new learning for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following XPath to test the `local-name()` of the element in a predicate and whether it's `text()` contains the phrase:

```
//*[(local-name() = "td" or local-name() = "div") and contains(text(), "Automation Server")]
```